# Document with multiple content elements

Tags: filenet-content-engine, ibm-content-navigator

I have documents within FileNet

1. Multiple content elements (both pdf's). When I open this document from ICN filmstrip view, I can scroll down to see both documents. If I double-click the document, it opens in a viewer and I can see both of them side by side.
2. Multiple content elements (excel and tiff). When I open this document from ICN filmstrip view, ***I can only see excel being rendered but not tiff***. If I double-click the document, it opens in a viewer and I can see both of them side by side.

any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Document` object in FileNet has a `MimeType` property and the content items themselves have a `ContentType` property. IIRC if not explicitly specified otherwise, the document's `MimeType` is the same as the `ContentType` of its first content element. I imagine the filmstrip view only evaluates the `MimeType` of the document, while the using Open, the `ContentType`s are being evaluated individually.

This means the filmstrip view thinks there are two Excel files, but the second content element has a non-Excel format.

Comment: so is there a solution for this?

Comment: I think not - at least if you're not willing to develop something. You could just make a viewer that uses the content element's `MimeType` and calls the navigator's default viewer for that mime type.